# Querying C# Dictionary using Lambda expressions

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, lambda

Let' say I have this Declared Dictionary:

```
 private static Dictionary<int, List<Models.APIAccessControl>> _APIRights = GetAPIRights();
```

Where the key represents the roleId, the value represent the class:

```
 public class APIAccessControl
{
    public APIControllerRoute ControllerRoute { get; set; }
    public APIActionRoute ActionRoute { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }

}
```

I am trying to check if the user is authorized to access this api.
My idea is to query the dictionary and get all list of APIAccessControl for the roles, then query those APIAccessControl lists for the APIActionRoute he is trying to navigate:

I got the Dictionary Values that contain those list for the roles i want, but how to cast a List of Values to List and make this query:

```
public static bool CanAccess(int[] roleIDs, APIActionRoute apiActionRoute)
   {
            bool canAccess = false;

            var apiAccessList = _APIRights.Where(x => roleIDs.Contains(x.Key)).Select(x => new { x.Value}).ToList();

      //Querying to get all List<Models.APIAccessControl> that has any matchig   APIActionRoute
    }
```

Comment: You can try to extract the list using Values property of Dictionary.

Comment: can you provide sample code for doing the casting and query, i am trying to write it in elegant, clean way. So, if you have any thoughts please share your code. Thanks

Comment: You'll have to use a loop over apiAccessList to get all the ActionRoutes and add them in a list. There is alternative. The only thing that you can do is to use Linq. Let me know if that clarifies anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the Select clause to give you the list you want:

```
var apiAccessList = _APIRights.Where(x => roleIDs.Contains(x.Key))
    .SelectMany(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

By not selecting to an anonymous class and by using the `SelectMany`, the list will be of type `Models.APIAccessControl`

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to iterate over the role ids first to take advantage of the Dictionaries lookup.

```
bool canAccess = false;
foreach(var roleId in roleIDs)
{
    List<Models.APIAccessControl> controls;
    if(_APIRights.TryGetValue(roleId, out controls))
    {
        canAccess = controls.Any(control => control.ActionRoute.Equals(apiActionRoute));
        if(canAccess)
            break;
    }
}
```

You'll have to make sure `Equals` actually does the type of comparison that you desire.  By default it will be a reference equality, and you'd have to overload it inside of `APIActionRoute` if you want value equality, or use a comparison of the desired properties instead.

A completely Linq version is a little bit messy

```
List<Models.APIAccessControl> controls;
bool canAccess = roleIDs.Any(
    r => _APIRights.TryGetValue(r, out controls) 
          && controls.Any(
              control => control.ActionRoute.Equals(apiActionRoute)));
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want `SelectMany`, which projects a "list of lists" into a single list:

```
var apiAccessList =
   _APIRights
   .Where(x => roleIDs.Contains(x.Key))
   .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
   .ToList();
```

You will then have every `APIAccessControl` object in one big list. It would no longer be grouped by roleID though. It might also have duplicates, which may or may not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the SelectMany may help.

```
public static bool CanAccess(int[] roleIDs, APIActionRoute apiActionRoute)
{
    return _APIRights.Where(x => roleIDs.Contains(x.Key))
        .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
        .Any(a => a.ActionRoute == apiActionRoute);
}
```